Jenkins.Instance is missing after installing AWSEBDeploymentBuilder
I am moving a job from an older Jenkins instance to a newer one. The new jenkins instance had some plugins missing, including AWSEBDeploymentBuilder. So after installing them, I am getting this error:
Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to jenkins-genieo-agent
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1787)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel$2.adapt(Channel.java:1037)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel$2.adapt(Channel.java:1033)
        at hudson.remoting.FutureAdapter.get(FutureAdapter.java:61)
        at br.com.ingenieux.jenkins.plugins.awsebdeployment.DeployerRunner.perform(DeployerRunner.java:64)
        at br.com.ingenieux.jenkins.plugins.awsebdeployment.AWSEBDeploymentBuilder.perform(AWSEBDeploymentBuilder.java:243)
        at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:123)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:101)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:71)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Jenkins.instance is missing. Read the documentation of Jenkins.getInstanceOrNull to see what you are doing wrong.
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.get(Jenkins.java:819)
    at br.com.ingenieux.jenkins.plugins.awsebdeployment.AWSClientFactory.getClientFactory(AWSClientFactory.java:63)
    at br.com.ingenieux.jenkins.plugins.awsebdeployment.AWSClientFactory.getClientFactory(AWSClientFactory.java:88)
    at br.com.ingenieux.jenkins.plugins.awsebdeployment.cmd.DeployerCommand$InitAWS.perform(DeployerCommand.java:143)
    at br.com.ingenieux.jenkins.plugins.awsebdeployment.cmd.DeployerChain.perform(DeployerChain.java:54)
    at br.com.ingenieux.jenkins.plugins.awsebdeployment.SlaveDeployerCallable.call(SlaveDeployerCallable.java:42)
    at br.com.ingenieux.jenkins.plugins.awsebdeployment.SlaveDeployerCallable.call(SlaveDeployerCallable.java:27)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:377)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(InterceptingExecutorService.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$2.adapt(Channel.java:1039)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$2.adapt(Channel.java:1033)
    at hudson.remoting.FutureAdapter.get(FutureAdapter.java:61)
    at br.com.ingenieux.jenkins.plugins.awsebdeployment.DeployerRunner.perform(DeployerRunner.java:64)
    at br.com.ingenieux.jenkins.plugins.awsebdeployment.AWSEBDeploymentBuilder.perform(AWSEBDeploymentBuilder.java:243)
Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: 311add04-e0a3-42e2-b5bc-c2b9d318d1f2
Caused: java.io.IOException: Deployment Failure
    at br.com.ingenieux.jenkins.plugins.awsebdeployment.AWSEBDeploymentBuilder.perform(AWSEBDeploymentBuilder.java:245)
    at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:123)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:101)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:71)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

This is my actual step:
step([$class: 'AWSEBDeploymentBuilder',
                applicationName: app_name_region_1,
                awsRegion: region_1_name,
                checkHealth: true,
                environmentName: stg_env_us_east_1,
                maxAttempts: maxAttempts,
                rootObject: war_file_name,
                sleepTime: sleepTime,
                versionLabelFormat: version_name_label,
                versionDescriptionFormat: "BRANCH: " + branch_name + ", " + "COMMIT: " + env.COMMIT_TO_BUILD + ", " + "TAG: " + env.TAG_TO_BUILD + ", " + "Version_label: " + ver_label,
                keyPrefix: bucket_folder
                ])

Looking online I learned it that this error means Jenkins isn't running or something, but obviously it is since I can run the job.
If there isn't a way to fix this, how can I do it manually?
Tried reinstalling the plugin, and this did not help either (/var/lib/jenkins already belongs to jenkins)
